# How to get the DOM ref of a child class component in a parent class component

Tags: reactjs, ref

I'm having a hard time understanding the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) on how to access the DOM ref of a child **class** component from the parent **class** component.

*Parent.js:*

```
import Child from './Child';

class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.refOfTheParent = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const parentDOM = this.refOfTheParent.current;
        //const childDOM = ???;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref={this.refOfTheParent}>
                <Child />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Parent;
```

*Child.js:*

```
class Child extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>Child component</div>
        );
    }
}

export default Child;
```

Could someone please finish this code for me where `childDOM` in `Parent::componentDidMount()` has the DOM ref of `<Child />`.

Bonus: How would it look if Parent AND Child are both connected with react-redux connect.

Comment: you want to access the div or you want to render some values from parent why I am asking because insted of using Refs you should use the State, using refs not recommended

Comment: I want the div in Child. Same as parentDOM, but for Child.

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Could be XY problem that needs to be solved in another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forwardRef`

```
class Child extend React.Component{
   render() {
      return (
        <div ref={this.props.forwardRef}> Child component </div>
      )
   }
}

export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <Child {...props} forwardRef={ref} />)
```

Then in parent

```
constructor(props) {
  // ...
  this.childRef = React.createRef();
}

render() {
    return (
       <div>
         <Child ref={this.childRef} />
       </div>
    )
}
```

more info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)

Comment: Could you update my code of Child.js with the forwardRef? I'm stupid

Comment: @horgen did not see you were talking about classes :)

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the ref in props in child component like

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Child from './Child';
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.refOfTheParent = React.createRef();
        this.childRef=React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const parentDOM = this.refOfTheParent.current;
         const childDom=this.childRef.current;
         console.log(childDom);
        //const childDOM = ???;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref={this.refOfTheParent}>
                <Child childRef={this.childRef}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Parent
```

Child Component

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
class Child extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div ref={this.props.childRef} id="1">Child component</div>
        );
    }
}

export default Child;
```

[Demo](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/3XSFiGNDUlGgEvbG?open=Hello.js&deferRun=1&preview)

Comment: Havent tried this yet, but wouldnt this return the class node instead of the DOM node of Child without forwardRef?

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: @horgen This is a good question, If you know the answer let me know. and if does work like what you expected then the next question is why we need `forwardRef` :) let me know