# In React, can I create a Component that also acts as a Forwarded Ref object?

Tags: reactjs, react-forwardref

I have a need to use forwarded refs

```
const InfoBox = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <div ref={ref} >
      <Rings >
      </Rings>
      <Tagline  />
    </div>
));
```

I also happen already have the code written like this

```
class InfoBox extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props)
   }


   render () {
      return (
      <div  >
        <Rings />
        <Tagline  />
      </div>
      )
   }
```

basically my InfoBox needs to be a Component because it holds some state, but I also want it to behave like an object that can receive refs from the parent and forward them down to the children (basically React.forwardRef)

After familiarizing myself with React.forwardRef, I can't figure out how to get it to work with my existing React components, which already have functionality attached to state.

do I need to separate the two objects, and wrap one within the other or is there a way I can achieve this in the same object?

the code that wraps Infobox looks like

```
class AppContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super()

    this.infobox_ref = React.createRef()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     // this.infobox_ref.current.innerHTML should return the inner HTML of the infobox
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <InfoBox ref={this.infobox_ref}> 
    )
  }
```

am I using forwarded refs correctly?

Comment: Regarding, "my InfoBox needs to be a Component because it holds some state,"....What version of React are you using? If React >=  16.8 then you can use hooks to hold states and emulate life cycle methods without turning `InfoBox` into a Class Component and keep the `forwardRef`.

Answer (score 0):

In React, the `ref` prop is not forwarded by default. In order to get a reference in a child component, you have 2 options:

1. Using a function component wrapped in the `forwardRef` function. You have already done this:

```
const InfoBox = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <div ref={ref} >
      <Rings >
      </Rings>
      <Tagline  />
    </div>
));
```

2. Changing the name of the `ref` prop.

```
// Parent Component
class AppContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super()
    this.infobox_ref = React.createRef()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     // this.infobox_ref.current.innerHTML should return the inner HTML of the infobox
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <InfoBox infoboxRef={this.infobox_ref}> 
    )
  }
}

// Child Component
class InfoBox extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div ref={this.props.infoboxRef}>
        <Rings />
        <Tagline  />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Of course, you can also combine them, allowing you to still pass to the `ref` prop from the parent, but consuming the "fixed" prop in the child class component, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53848662/10054418) by @tubu13:

```
class InfoBox extend React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.props.infoboxRef}>
        <Rings />
        <Tagline  />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <InfoBox {...props} infoboxRef={ref} />)
```

Comment: my objects are still coming out as  {current: null} when examined from componentDidMount in the AppContainer

Comment: I created this code sandbox which shows a ref with a different name: https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-glade-rt8jq @JasonFB . As you can see, the console logs the right value.

Comment: thank you this is helpful. I think my problem might be that I have created an array of refs, and am trying to pass it down by array index `ref={this.marbles_refs_array[i]}`

Comment: an array of refs should also work: see https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-chatterjee-lkkky @JasonFB

Comment: @JasonFB If you can put your specific case in a code sandbox, I can take a look.